# Porque aparece undifined index?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tenho um código onde envia umas informações mas nao está a enviar o totalcopias nao sei porque.Envio tudo o resto ate o ficheiro menos o total copias. Usei um echo="$totalcopias" para vez o valor da variavel e o valor ta la mas quando tento enviar fica undifined index.

```
    $mailto = $_POST['mailto'];
    $mailSub = $_POST['mailsub'];
    $escola=$_POST['escola']; 
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $processo=$_POST['processo']; 
    $disciplina=$_POST['disciplina']; 
    $a4cor = $_POST['a4cor'];
    $a4preto = $_POST['a4preto'];
    $a3cor=$_POST['a3cor'];
    $a3preto=$_POST['a3preto'];
    $impressao=$_POST['impressao'];  
    $observacoes=$_POST['observacoes'];
    $totalcopias=$a4cor + $a4preto + $a3cor + $a3preto;
    $target = "ficheiros/".basename($_FILES['ficheiro']['name']);
```

```
$mail ->Body='<h2>Escola: '.$_POST['escola'].'<br>Nome: '.$_POST['nome'].'<br>Processo: '.$_POST['processo'].'<br>Email: '.$_POST['email'].'<br>Disciplina: '.$_POST['disciplina'].'<br>Fotocópias A4 a cor: '.$_POST['a4cor'].'<br>Fotocópias A4 a preto: '.$_POST['a4preto'].'<br>Fotocópias A3 a cor: '.$_POST['a3cor'].'<br>Fotocópias A3 a preto: '.$_POST['a3preto'].'<br>Impressão: '.$_POST['impressao'].'<br>Observacões: '.$_POST['observacoes'].'<br>Total de fotocópias: '.$_POST['totalcopias'].'</h2>';
```

Comment: Verifique se em seu form ele contem esse name

Comment: `$totalcopias` é uma variável, não existe na superglobal `$_POST['totalcopias']`. Aliás, nenhuma das variáveis que definiu você utilizou depois, o que não fez sentido algum.

Comment: Tenho um input com value 0

Comment: Essas variaveis sao apenas para envio pq eu envio para o email e para uma base de dados

Comment: declara $valorcopias = 0; antes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou declara e inicaliza-la

```
$totalcopias = 0;
$mailto = $_POST['mailto'];
    $mailSub = $_POST['mailsub'];
    $escola=$_POST['escola']; 
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $processo=$_POST['processo']; 
    $disciplina=$_POST['disciplina']; 
    $a4cor = $_POST['a4cor'];
    $a4preto = $_POST['a4preto'];
    $a3cor=$_POST['a3cor'];
    $a3preto=$_POST['a3preto'];
    $impressao=$_POST['impressao'];  
    $observacoes=$_POST['observacoes'];
    $totalcopias=$a4cor + $a4preto + $a3cor + $a3preto;
    $target = "ficheiros/".basename($_FILES['ficheiro']['name']);
```

Comment: undifined index a mesma

Comment: oi? não entendi o que quis dizer... fica com mesmo erro?

Comment: sim ja tentei mudar o nome da variavel tmb

Comment: aperece erro aqui .$_POST['totalcopias'].' que ta undifined mas eu ja usei um echo para saber o valor e mostra o valor certo

Comment: verifica se todos os valores que vem do form esta igual aos que enviam para esse total copias

Comment: $a4cor + $a4preto + $a3cor + $a3preto;.

Verifica se todos esses vem certo

Comment: $totalcopias=$a4cor + $a4preto + $a3cor + $a3preto;
    echo "$totalcopias";

Comment: 66
Notice: Undefined index: totalcopias in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\enviar.php on line 71

Comment: qual a linha 71? esse $totalcopias=$a4cor + $a4preto + $a3cor + $a3preto;

Comment: se der puxa um chat ai

Comment: linha 71 toda $mail ->Body='<h2>Escola: '.$_POST['escola'].'<br>Nome: '.$_POST['nome'].'<br>Processo: '.$_POST['processo'].'<br>Email: '.$_POST['email'].'<br>Disciplina: '.$_POST['disciplina'].'<br>Fotocópias A4 a cor: '.$_POST['a4cor'].'<br>Fotocópias A4 a preto: '.$_POST['a4preto'].'<br>Fotocópias A3 a cor: '.$_POST['a3cor'].'<br>Fotocópias A3 a preto: '.$_POST['a3preto'].'<br>Impressão: '.$_POST['impressao'].'<br>Observacões: '.$_POST['observacoes'].'<br>Total de fotocópias: '.$_POST['totalcopias'].'</h2>';

Comment: Repara no Total de fotocópias: '.$_POST['totalcopias'].... você não está usando um post dele para poder somar... tu está usando ele internamente com a declaração da variavel $totalcopias=$a4cor + $a4preto + $a3cor + $a3preto;

...tem que colocar o $totalcopias e não $_POST['totalcopias']

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Comment: sim agora deu certo